# protoc-gen-go: program not found or is not executable

Tags: grpc, grpc-go, protobuf-go

I'm trying to make a microservice app using protobuf and go. But I faced with problem that I've never faced before. I have my **UserService.proto** file that I want to compile. But when I start `protoc --go_out=. --go-grpc_out=. UserService.proto` command it shows me

```
protoc-gen-go: program not found or is not executable
Please specify a program using absolute path or make sure the program is available in your PATH system variable
--go_out: protoc-gen-go: Plugin failed with status code 1.
```

I checked my .zshrc file but it seemed ok:

```bash
export PATH=$PATH:$(go env GOPATH)/bin
```

I tried to set gopath and gobin manually, but it also didn't help me:

```bash
export GOPATH=$(go env GOPATH)
export GOBIN=$(go env GOPATH)/bin
```

I also downloaded protoc-gen-go plugin and it is contained in bin folder of go:
[image]

So what can be the problem? If you know, please tell me. I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: Unfamiliar with MacOS but, you should be able to confirm that `protoc-gen-go-grpc` is correctly `PATH`'d using `which protoc-gen-go-grpc` (to show the found binary) and then `ls -la $(which protoc-gen-go-grpc)` to confirm that your user can execute it. Did you `go install google.golang.org/grpc/cmd/protoc-gen-go-grpc@latest` the plugin? That should ensure that you're getting the correct binary for your platform.

Comment: @DazWilkin Thanks for answer. Yes,  protoc-gen-go-grpc is correctly PATH'd. I checked it by commands that you provided and they execute correctly. And yes, I installed the plugin that u mentioned.

Comment: Weird. What is the result of `protoc-gen-go-grpc --version`?

Comment: @DazWilkin It says ```protoc-gen-go-grpc 1.3.0```

Comment: Hmmm.... So, we know `protoc-gen-go-grpc` is installed, executable and the latest version.  Hang on, it says `protoc-gen-go` ... ugh, my apologies, that's the other plugin. You need to install `protoc-gen-go` as well: `go install google.golang.org/protobuf/cmd/protoc-gen-go@latest`

Comment: Oh, thank you so much! Now everything is working!

Comment: Sorry for missing that initially; I'm going to blame New Year's Day tiredness